# ParseClient.Initialize("Application ID", ".NET Key") Error. Windows Phone 8 - Parse.com

Tags: windows-phone-8, parse-platform

I'm trying to connect to a Windows Phone 8 app I created on Parse.com by following the quick start guide at 
https://www.parse.com/apps/quickstart#parse_data/mobile/windows_phone/existing

When I run the app (c#, XAML), an exception is raised in the method: App() - the constructor, located in the file: App.xaml.c.

```
            try
            {
                ParseClient.Initialize("I inserted my Application ID here", "my .NET key");
            }
            catch (ParseException pex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("\n\n**** ParseException Error ***** \n\n");
                Debug.WriteLine(pex.Message);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("\n\n\n**** Exception Error  **** \n\n" + ex.Message);
            }
```

ParseClient.Initialize raises an exception: The error message is: 
A first chance exception of type 'System.NotImplementedException' occurred in Parse.Phone.DLL

As a result, I don't even see the start screen when I run the app. It crashes before it starts.

Thanks for any suggestions/help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try reverting to 1.2.16

```
  unInstall-Package parse
  Install-Package parse -Version 1.2.16
```

this helped me.

cheers

Comment: Thanks a lot. This solved my issue. I tried using package 1.2.15 but 1.2.30 and both gave me the errors. 1.2.16 worked just fine. Thanks.

Comment: I know. I last few hours trying it out. I cannot believe that NotImplementedException got its way into release...

Comment: Atleast initialization works but i cant get any push notification and it seems the developer of parse are slow to respond

Comment: I would file a report/feedback to Parse so that they are aware of these issues. You're right, it's interesting that the bug made it to release.

Comment: It seems that test push notifications (from dashboard) are not working.  According to this post they are aware of this and no ETA (10 months)

https://www.parse.com/questions/windows-phone-8-cannot-send-push-from-dashboard

This one is the same:

https://www.parse.com/questions/windows-phone-and-push-notification